# Reproject GeoDataframe not converting geometry properly

Tags: projection, geopandas

I am using Geopandas to create a geodataframe by reading a shapefile (.shp) which has already projected to EPSG:3735 (Ohio State Plane South, US ft). Now I want to join another geodataframe to this one. The second geodataframe was created by reading a .csv file which contains x, y coordinates in lon, lat format. So the I define the crs of the second geodataframe as EPSG:4326 (WGS 1984). To use the spatial join function, the crs of the two geodataframe need to be the same, so I tried to use to_crs to reproject the first geodatafame to EPSG:4326. Before reprojection, the Geodataframe gdf looks like this:

|  | TAZ | County | AreaType | District | FAZ | SHAPE_Leng | SHAPE_Area | ID | zone_type | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656 | 2261 | 029 | 1 | 248 | 16 | 46500.252569 | 1.147235e+08 | 2261 | OD | POLYGON ((1286831.480 474763.929, 1286845.315 ... |

Then if I write:

```py
gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

The result turns out to be like this:

|  | TAZ | County | AreaType | District | FAZ | SHAPE_Leng | SHAPE_Area | ID | zone_type | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656 | 2261 | 029 | 1 | 248 | 16 | 46500.252569 | 1.147235e+08 | 2261 | OD | POLYGON ((inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, inf inf, ... |

I also tried to convert the second gdf from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3735, but the points geometry in the second gdf will also become Point(inf, inf). I am not sure what's wrong here. Can anyone suggest a good method to repoject polygons in geodataframe?

I just tried some other crs later. Some of them will work (not turning into infinites), such as 3785, 3035. I also tried some other State Plane PCS, but some of them work while other don't. Ohio south (3735) and north (3734) not working. Indiana east (2965) is not working but west (2966) is working. Also project to NAD83 GCS (4269) is not working.

Comment: your dataframe is malformed. Your geometry only exists for one row and is in the wrong column

Comment: @PaulH The dataframe is not the problem. It's jus because of my editing when I posted my question. I'm new to stack overflow, so maybe I did something wrong when editing. But the dataframe itself in python has no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just figured it out. Instead of initializing the second `gdf` from the .csv file with a WGS 1984 (4326), it should be set to NAD 1983 (4269). Both GCS use lat and long so I guess converting from one to another will cause some trouble. Then, I am able to use `to_crs` to convert the `gdf` from `EPSG:4269` to `EPSG:3735`, since 3735 is a PCS using NAD83. So I guess it may cause some trouble when directly projecting data from one GCS to another PCS using other GCS in Geopandas. I didn't check the source code but to avoid similar issues, I would say be cautious when trying to project using `to_crs` if the destination crs is in another GCS.

Answer (score 0):

A thing you can check is whether `gdf` has the correct coordinate system set. You can do that with `gdf.crs`. If it is not EPSG:3735, but something else, this can lead to the infinities you are seeing.

If it's wrong, it probably makes sense to investigate why. But in any case, you can overwrite the wrong value with `set_crs`:

```py
gdf = gdf.set_crs("EPSG:3735")
gdf_proj = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think that is the issue. The crs of the gdf is 3735. Actually I just tried some other crs today. Some of them will work (not turning into infinites), such as 3785, 3035. I also tried some other State Plane PCS, but some of them work while other don't. Ohio south (3735) and north (3734) not working. Indiana east (2965) is not working but west (2966) is working. Also project to NAD83 GCS (4269) is not working. This is weird and I don't know if it's just me having this issue.